# Python 3 Not Registering Input

Tags: python-3.x, loops, input

```
  9     encrypt = input("Enter E to encrypt, D to decrypt, and Q to quit: ")                                                                                                                                
 10     print(encrypt)
 11     while encrypt.lower() != "e" or "d" or "q":
 12         encrypt = input("Please try again with a valid input (E, D, or Q): ")
 13         print(encrypt)
 14 
 15     if encrypt.lower() == "q":
 16         sys.exit()
```

I have this loop to continue looking for input until it's either e, d, or q. When I run it, no input triggers to leave the loop, even if it's one of those three characters. The only thing I can do to get out of the program period is to input an EOF error. I'm sure it's something stupid I'm doing wrong but I can't find anything syntactically wrong, I'm not getting any errors, and I'm not even using any extra libraries past what's built in to python 3. Any clues?

Comment: Your loop condition will never be false. You can't compare values using `or` like that. See the dupe.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the redundancy, I didn't see that in my attempted research

Comment: No problem. This is an extraordinarily common mistake. This gets asked at least a couple times a day.